# продвинуть Tex Live под Debian GNU/Linux c TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian до TeX Live 2022/Debian (под Debian 12), пакеты не находятся

Tags: debian, tex

Я пытаюсь продвинуть Tex Live под Debian GNU/Linux
c версии  TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian (под старым Debian)
до  TeX Live 2022/Debian (под Debian 12).
Какие-то пакеты не находятся, и я не знаю, каков правильный способ их установить.
Исходник  foo.tex  использует стиль  llncs.cls  и начинается так:

```
documentclass[a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}             % от автора, вместо cp1251
\usepackage{enumitem}                    % для изменения промежутка в перечислении
\usepackage{url}                         % для ссылок, которые
\usepackage[unicode, pdftex]{hyperref}   % кликаются
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
...
```

Команда  $ pdflatex foo
работает правильно под  TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian (в старом Debian).
А под  TeX Live 2022/Debian
(под Debian 12, TeX установлен по кнопке из меню Debian)
она сообщает

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)
(preloaded format=pdflatex)  restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./manual.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-01-16> (./llncs.cls
Document Class: llncs 2017/09/04 v2.19
 LaTeX document class for Lecture Notes in Computer Science
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/aliascnt.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

! LaTeX Error: File `utf8x.def' not found.
```

Каков правильный способ установки нужных пакетов для этого обновлённого
TeX Live  (для обновлённого Debian) ?
Я просмотрел список пакетов, выдаваемых `apt list`, там есть строчка
`bf-utf-source/stable 0.08+nmu2 all`
и много строчек, включающих слово utf8.
И к чему-то из них применить `apt-get install` ?

Наверное и какие-то другие пакеты не найдутся ...

Answer (score 0):

Я узнал, что дело не в версиях ТeX или системы, а только во множестве установленных для TeX пакетов. И есть простой способ установить все известные пакеты для TeX Live - это установить пакет TeX Live Full.
В Линуксе это делается так:

```
$ su 
...
$ apt update
$ apt install texlive-full
```

(я из Интернета полу-случайно узнал имя texlive-full).
Последняя команда узнаёт версию операционной системы на компьютере, версию Tex Live, находит в Интернете хорошее место, где расположены все пакеты для TeX Live для этой версии, скачивает эти пакеты, разворачивает и устанавливает их.
На моей машине в 3 GHz это заняло примерно 30 минут и 12 Gb места на диске.
Зато теперь все пакеты находятся.